# Why is addition of powers of $\omega$ absorptive?

Tags: set-theory

Why is it the case that if $\alpha<\beta$, $\omega^\alpha+\omega^\beta=\omega^\beta$? Is it because $\omega^\alpha+\omega^\beta=\omega^\alpha(1+\omega^{\beta-\alpha})=\omega^\alpha\omega^{\beta-\alpha}=\omega^\beta$?

Comment: What is $\beta-\alpha$? It is not well-defined in general. However, you may use similar thing: you can prove that if $\alpha<\beta$ then there is a $\gamma$ s.t. $\beta=\alpha+\gamma$.

Comment: Yeah, that $\gamma$ was what I meant by $\beta-\alpha$. Fortunately, it's in the right order.